# Late 70s/early 80s kids sci-fi novel with dying spacecraft captain

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

A strange spacecraft lands in a town, the (human) captain is dying and children take over the operation of the spaceship.

That's all I remember, it bugs me not to know.  I'm trying to find it for my kids to read, they have just started "A Wrinkle in Time".

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Hi there.  I've cleaned up your text a little and changed the tags and title to help you get an answer.  If this changes the intended meaning of your question please feel free to revert these edits.

Comment: What language was it in?

Comment: @ScifiDad.  This sounds very familiar. Do the children accidently launch the spaceship and get stranded in space. One of the boys (the "nerdy" one" who knows math, etc.) has to try and learn how to pilot it to return.  He then becomes "popular" with the other children including a young girl his own age. This puts him into conflict with one of the other boys who is normally the "popular" one.

Comment: If this is correct, I also recall in the group of children there is one boy who becomes isolated and afraid (i.e. regresses to wanting his mom to the point of reality denial of what is going on).  There is a very young girl nicknamed "Beauty" because of her angelical features.  I seem to remember the setting for the children was Great Britain, specifically England. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @JimmyShelter - Thank you

Comment: @beichst - Thank you - I believe you're heading in the right direction. Those points seem to be familiar - wasn't too sure about the setting though but I may be wrong

Comment: @MrLister - it was in English. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Thanks! Based on the additional information I have tracked it down. It is Nicholas Fisk's *[Space Hostages](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1087684.Space_Hostages)*, published in 1967.

[image: Book cover - *Space Hostages*]

> A crazed and dying Flight Lieutenant, nine village children, a top-secret spacecraft - all of them out of control and adrift in space! Someone must take charge. But who?
>
> Brylo has the brains, but not the personality, so it is the powerful young bully Tony who sets himself up as Captain - and steers the ship and its cargo of children towards new and horrifying dangers...

Comment: that is great! Glad I could help.

Comment: @ScifiDad: When you return, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.